# AWS EC2: Internal server error when huge number of api calls at the same time from jmeter

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, jmeter, amazon-rds

We have made the backend of a mobile AP in laravel and mysql. The application is hosted on AWS Ec2 and using RDS mysql database.

We are stress testing the app using jmeter. When we send upto 1000 API requests from jmeter, it seems to work fine. However, when we send more than 1000 (roughly) requests in parallel, The jmeter starts getting internal server error (500) as a response for many requests. the internal 500 error percentage increases as we increase the number of APIs

Normally, we would expect that if we increase the APIs, they should be queued and the response should slow if the server is out of resources. We also monitored the resources on the server and they never reached even 50% of the available resources

Is there any timeout setting or any other possible setting that I could tweak so that the we dont get the internal server error before reaching 80% of the resource usage

Regards
Syed

Comment: What do you mean by "resources on the server?"  There are many resources: network capacity, CPU capacity, RAM, IO capacity, context switching capacity, etc etc etc.  Correctly figuring out which resource is the bottleneck under load-test load is quite difficult. It takes deep understanding of how your host OS works and how to monitor it.

Comment: You are right. We have monitored memory and CPU only.

Answer (score 1):

`500` is the externally visible symptom of some sort of failure in the server delivering your API.  You should look at the error log of that server to see details of the failure.

If you are using php scripts to deliver the API, your mysql (rds) server may be running out of connections.  Here's how that might work.

A php-driven web server under heavy load runs a lot of php instances. Each php instance opens up one or more connections to the mysql server. When there are too many `php instances` x `connections per instance` the mysql server starts refusing more of them.

Here's what you need to do: restrict the number of php instances your web server is allowed to use at a time.  When you restrict that number, incoming requests will queue up (in the TCP connect queue of your OS's communication stack). Then, when an instance is available to serve each item in the queue it will do so.

Apache has a [MaxRequestWorkers parameter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers), with a default extremely large value of 256. Try setting it much lower, for example to 32, and see whether your problem changes.

If you can shrink the number of request workers, you paradoxically may improve high-load performance. Serializing many requests often generates better throughput than trying to do many of them in parallel.

The same goes for the number of active connections to your MySQL server. It obviously depends on the nature of the queries you use, but generally speaking fewer concurrent queries improves performance. So, you won't solve a real-world problem by adding MySQL connections.

You should be aware that the kind of load imposed by server-hammering tools like jmeter is not representative of real world load.  1000 simultaneous jmeter operations without failure is a very good result.  If your load-testing setup is robust and powerful, you will always be able to bring your server system to its knees. So, deciding when to stop is an important part of a load testing plan. If this were my system I would stop at 1000 for now.

For your app to be robust in the field, you probably should program it to respond to `500` status by waiting a random amount of time and trying again.

Comment: thanks a lot for such informative reply. Yes, the app is hosted on apache on AWS ec2 instance. I also know that 1000 parallel requests in 1 second is without failure is quite a good result. However, I want to know when the server will come down on its knees but even before the server reaches 50% of resources, we start getting the internal 500 errors. By the way, will increasing the mysql max connections help too?